# Python Find all letter chars in string and surround with text

Tags: string, python-3.4

So lets say I have a string that says "m * x + b", I want to find any letter chars, other than x, and surround them with text.

In this example, output should be "var['m'] * x + var['b']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tiny regular expression solves your problem:

```py
import re

s = "m * x + b"
print re.sub("([a-wyzA-Z])", r"var['\1']", s)
```

Output:

```
var['m'] * x + var['b']
```

Explanation:

- `[a-wyzA-Z]` matches all characters within the brackets: a-w, y, z and A-Z (so basically every letter but x)
- `(...)` makes the found match accessible later via `\1`
- `r"var['\1']" is the replacement referring to the match`\1`